# HTML to PDF dimensions incorrect

Tags: python, html, pdf

I'm trying to autogenerate a PDF using Python and using HTML to style the report and then just convert it to a PDF. I'm using two libraries for generating a PDF from HTML(`pdfkit` and `weasyprint`) and I can't get either to work.

Here's the HTML code I'm trying to render:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <style>
        html {
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            width: 816px;
            height: 1056px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Monthly Report</title>
</head>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="width: 100% !important;">
    <h2 style="text-align: center">MONTHLY REPORT</h2>
    <img src="static/company1_logo.png" height="56" width="150"/>
    <img src="static/company2_logo.png" style="float: right" height="56" width="137"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I'm using for `pdfkit`:

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'test.pdf')
```

The output PDF has extremely small dimensions and is barely readable. Alternatively for `weasyprint`:

```
pdf = HTML('test.html').write_pdf()
with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pdf)
```

And this looks better but it only loosely follows my CSS (i.e. the images aren't resized, the top margin can't be changed). Is there any way to create an HTML page which can easily be converted to a PDF/what am I doing wrong with these?

Comment: I've had good luck with the command-line program wkhtmltopdf. It implements a WebKit layer, as well as a JavaScript engine. Since Python is a good glue language, you could invoke the shell command in your program.

Comment: @amphetamachine Hmm, I tried using it and it results in the same type of PDF as invoking pdfkit - everything seems to be really small :/

Comment: I just rendered it with `wkhtmltopdf in.html out.pdf` and it looks fine to me. The PDF looks exactly like it does in the browser.

Comment: I see, it follows the CSS it just seems all zoomed out (i.e. a 367x137 png appears to be taking up less than half of those dimensions). Is this more a problem with my HTML?

Comment: The height and width of the body don't affect the size of the PDF document, just like the height and width of a web page don't affect your browser's window size. By default `wkhtmltopdf` sets the dimensions of the PDF to 8.5in x 11in. If you want it to generate a PDF of a different size, you'll have to specify it on the command line. I think it renders in 300 dpi, so the page is 8.5*300=2550px across.

Comment: I changed the dimensions and that appears to have done it. Also interestingly enough, I found that the pdfkit library for Python is actually a wrapper of wkhtmltopdf so it can all be done without a subprocess to wkhtmltopdf. Thanks for all of the help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146217/discussion-between-finaris-and-amphetamachine).

Answer (score 3):

In `pdfkit` which is a wrapper of [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt)  the `dpi` value is set default to `96`

To generate good-quality printable PDFs, try with some dpi value between 300 to 400 in `options` of pdfkit.

Below helped me

```
options = {
         'dpi': 365,
         'page-size': 'A4',
         'margin-top': '0.25in',
         'margin-right': '0.25in',
         'margin-bottom': '0.25in',
         'margin-left': '0.25in',
         'encoding': "UTF-8",
         'custom-header' : [
            ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
         ],
         'no-outline': None,
    }

 pdfkit.from_string(soup, file_path, options = options)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be late to the game, but I had a similar issue... There are additional parameters to be aware of. First, try setting `print-media-type` to True; this helps the pdf render as close to the to your HTML file as possible. Additionally, set the `disable-smart-shrinking` to True. With this set to True, you should not getting any unwanted white space in the pdf file (that is, if you have created the html/css to be the size that you want it in the first place).

This were the options I had set that fixed my issue of the pdf rendering in a weird way.

```
options = {"page-size":"Letter",
           "margin-top":"0in",
            "margin-bottom":"0in",
           "margin-left":"0in",
           "margin-right":"0in",
           'encoding': "UTF-8",
           "print-media-type": True,
           'disable-smart-shrinking': True,
           }

# Convert HTML to PDF
pdfkit.from_file('./input_file.html', 'output_file.pdf', configuration=config, options=options)
```

You should be able to alter these options to fit your use case. I hope this helps!